# Laravel lumen micro-framework handling wrong request methods

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

In `Laravel`, we can simply check request method by this method:

```
Route::any('getToken', 'TransactionController@getPaymentToken');

public function getPaymentToken(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        echo json_encode(['code' => '-200', 'message' => "Bad Request Method"]);
        return;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to do this method on `Lumen`, but I get this error:

```
Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::any()
```

My test:

```
$app->any('getToken', 'TransactionController@getPaymentToken');

public function getPaymentToken(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        echo json_encode(['code' => '-200', 'message' => "Bad Request Method"]);
        return;
    }
}
```

I want to handle wrong user requests and I don't like the user to get `lumen` errors, such as the pasted error.

Answer (score 2):

Lumen doesn't support `any` request method. You may define them separately:

```
foreach ([
    'GET',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'PATCH',
    'DELETE',
    'OPTIONS',
] as $method) {
    $app->addRoute($method, 'getToken', 'TransactionController@getPaymentToken');
}
```

Comment: In your 'routes.php' file.

Comment: then, can i use condition on controller's action to check that? for example: `if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        echo json_encode(['code' => '-200', 'message' => "Bad Request Method"]);
        return;
    }`

Comment: OK sir, i try to test, please let me to check and accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Lumen doesn't have `$app->any()` method. It uses `FastRoute` instead of `Illuminate/Routing`.

You can install `Illuminate/Routing` if you want. Why would you just not use `$app->get()` if you are not allowing `POST` requests ?

Comment: my application is web service and user maybe request wrong method on my application, for example route method is get and user request is post. then `Lumen` throw error and i dont like that